# AutoHotkey not work in PLSQL Developer

Tags: plsql, autohotkey

In win7 I can't use the macro functionality in PLSQL Developer 7.0, so I want to use AutoHotkey to solve the problem. Unfortunately it dose not work as well, is it the problem of AutoHotkey or PLSQL Developer? Can I solve the problem by configure the AutoHotkey.

I know PLSQL Developer 9.0 fix the macro function in win7, but I only have the licence for PLSQL Developer 7.0.

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your install of AutoHotkey should have AU3 Win Spy (look in start menu).  Run it, click on PSQL Developer, and click back on WinSpy.  Copy and paste what it gives you.  By the way, if you don't have AutoHotkey_L, [please get it](http://l.autohotkey.net/).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Thanks.I solve my problem,I need to run AutoHotkey as Administrator